# La variable no almacena valor

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy haciendo un programa basado en el juego de siete y medio de la baraja española, el ejercicio es este: [SIETE Y MEDIO](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aGzVKJN52kKPqyVcBUp9O0qKFnSZcU96).
El main esta en la clase GameController.java y haciendo un degug step into me di cuente que la variable valorJ no almacena ningún valor y sin embargo cuando la imprimes si se muestra su valor. 
La explicación de como debería funcionar el programa así como las normas del juego están explicados en el pdf.
El codigo del main es el siguiente:

```java
package sieteymedia;

import java.util.Scanner;
import recursos.Baraja;
import recursos.Carta;

public class GameController {
    Baraja[] baraja = new Baraja[40];


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre;
        boolean bj = true;//booleano para controlar el bucle principal del juego
        boolean bju = true;//booleano para controlar el bucle del jugador
        boolean bba = true;//booleano para controlar el bucle de la banca
        int apuestaTotal = 0;
        double valorJ = 0;
        double valorB = 0;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Como te llamas? ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
        Jugador jugador = new Jugador(nombre);
        Jugador banca = new Jugador("BANCA");
        inicio(jugador);

        Baraja b = new Baraja();
        b = crearBaraja(b);
        b.barajaCartas();

        while (bj) {
            while (bju) {                
                System.out.println("¿Cuanto deseas apostar? (min: 10 creditos)");
                int apuesta = entrada.nextInt();
                apuestaTotal += apuesta;
                entrada.nextLine();
                jugador.nuevaCarta(b.daCartas(1)[0]);

                System.out.println("Tus cartas son:");
                apuesta(jugador, valorJ);
                System.out.printf("Tu apuesta total en la jugada es de: %d créditos\n", apuestaTotal);

                if (valorJ >= 7.5) {
                    bju = false;
                }else if (valorJ < 7.5) {
                    System.out.println("¿Pides [C]arta o te [P]lantas?");
                    String carta = entrada.nextLine();
                    carta = carta.toUpperCase();

                    if (carta.equals("C")) {
                        valorJ = 0;
                        bju = true;
                    }else{
                        bju = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Tus cartas son:");
            apuesta(jugador, valorJ);
            System.out.printf("Tu apuesta total en la jugada es de: %d créditos\n", apuestaTotal);

            if (valorJ == 7.5) {
                System.out.println("Wow!! Siete y media!");
            }

            System.out.println("Voy a sacar mis cartas...");
            System.out.println("Pulsa [RET] para continuar...");

            while (bba) {
                banca.nuevaCarta(b.daCartas(1)[0]);
                apuesta(banca, valorB);

                if (valorB >= 7.5 || valorB == valorJ) {
                    bba = false;
                }else if (valorB < valorJ) {
                    valorB = 0;
                    bba = true;
                }
            }

            if (valorB >= valorJ && valorB <= 7.5) {
                System.out.println("----> Ohhh!!! Yo gano!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("----> Me pasé! Tú ganas!!");
            }


            System.out.println("¿Quieres continuar? [S/N]");
            String seguir = entrada.nextLine();
            seguir = seguir.toUpperCase();

            if (seguir.equals("S")) {
                b.reiniciaBaraja();
                jugador.reiniciaMano();
                banca.reiniciaMano();
                bj = true;
            }else{
                bj = false;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void juegaMano(int n){}

    public static void inicio(Jugador j){
        System.out.printf("Bienvenido, %s. Vamos a jugar!\n", j.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Pero antes, las reglas:");
        System.out.println("- Yo haré de banca");
        System.out.println("- Antes de pedir una carta, debes hacer una apuesta.");
        System.out.println("- La apuesta no puede ser inferior a 10");
        System.out.println("- Puedes sacar todas las cartas que quieras. Recuerda, las figuras (10, 11 y\n" +
"12) valen medio punto y, el resto, su valor");
        System.out.println("- Si la suma de los valores de las cartas sacadas es superior a 7 y medio, se\n" +
"pierde");
        System.out.println("- Puedes plantarte en cualquier momento");
        System.out.println("- Yo, al ser la banca, estoy obligado a sacar cartas hasta superar tu jugada o\n" +
"pasarme");
        System.out.println("- Ganas si obtienes una jugada de valor superior a la mía");
        System.out.println("- En caso de empate, gano yo");
        System.out.println("- En caso de que uno de los dos saque 7 y media, se pagará el doble");
        System.out.println("- En caso de quedarte sin crédito, el juego finalizará");
        System.out.println("Tu credito actual es de: " + j.getCredito() + " creditos");
        System.out.println("EMPECEMOS!!!");
    }

    public static Baraja crearBaraja(Baraja b){
        //OROS
        b.setCartas("OROS", 1, 0);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 2, 1);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 3, 2);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 4, 3);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 5, 4);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 6, 5);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 7, 6);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 10, 7);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 11, 8);
        b.setCartas("OROS", 12, 9);

        //BASTOS
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 1, 10);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 2, 11);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 3, 12);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 4, 13);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 5, 14);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 6, 15);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 7, 16);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 10, 17);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 11, 18);
        b.setCartas("BASTOS", 12, 19);

        //ESPADAS
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 1, 20);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 2, 21);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 3, 22);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 4, 23);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 5, 24);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 6, 25);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 7, 26);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 10, 27);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 11, 28);
        b.setCartas("ESPADAS", 12, 29);

        //COPAS
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 1, 30);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 2, 31);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 3, 32);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 4, 33);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 5, 34);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 6, 35);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 7, 36);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 10, 37);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 11, 38);
        b.setCartas("COPAS", 12, 39);

        return b;
    }

    public static void apuesta(Jugador j, double valor){
        for (Carta carta : j.getCartas()) {
            if (carta != null) {
                switch (carta.getValor()) {
                    case 10:
                        System.out.print("[" + carta.getPalo() + ": S]");
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        System.out.print("[" + carta.getPalo() + ": C]");
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        System.out.print("[" + carta.getPalo() + ": R]");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.print("[" + carta.getPalo() + ": " + carta.getValor() + "]");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Valor de la jugada: ");

        for (Carta carta : j.getCartas()) {
            if (carta != null) {
                switch (carta.getValor()) {
                    case 10:
                    case 11:
                    case 12:
                        valor += 0.5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        valor += carta.getValor();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(valor);
    }
}
```

Si necesitais el codigo del resto de las clases avisar.
Aquí dejo el trozo de código donde esta el problema.
La variable valorJ siempre esta en 0 pero si hago el `System.out.println()` me imprime el valor que debería tener.

```java
if (valorJ >= 7.5) {
    bju = false;
}else if (valorJ < 7.5) {
    System.out.println("¿Pides [C]arta o te [P]lantas?");
    String carta = entrada.nextLine();
    carta = carta.toUpperCase();

    if (carta.equals("C")) {
        valorJ = 0;
        bju = true;
    }else{
        bju = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema? si la variable imprime el valor cual seria tu duda?

Comment: Hola @JPilado. Si imprime el valor, quiere decir que previamente lo ha almacenado. Tal vez, al momento de hacer el debug, se está ubicando justo en la línea de asignación, eso quiere decir que aún no lo ha recibido, por lo que no mostrará el valor hasta la línea siguiente posterior a la asignación, no sucede con todos los debugger, pero tal vez le esté sucediendo en este caso.

Comment: El problema es que hay un if donde comparo el valor de la variable con 7.5 en donde si es mayor o igual cambio el valor del booleano bju a false para salir del bucle y en el else if comparo su valor denuovo con 7.5 y si es menor pido al usuario si se planta o quiere carta. SIEMPRE ME ENTRA POR EL ELSE

Comment: @Moisés Huamán C. edite la pregunta, espero que este un poco mas clara y que entendáis la duda